# How to display math in LaTeX font using Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fonts, latex

I would like to display mathematical symbols in the conventional LaTeX Font using C# in Visual Studio 2010. I do NOT want to use the LaTeX equation editing machinery, I only want to use the
traditional LaTeX font family, which I believe is called Computer Modern. Using mathematical
symbols in this font, I would like to build my own equation editor.

I have already downloaded and installed the Computer Modern font, and indeed I can now select this font from the list in Visual Studio. However, as a result all the text characters are indeed displayed in the Computer Modern font, all the mathematical symbols are NOT; the latter seem to be completely unaffected by changing the Font Family property.

For example, I have a label whose content property is a text string which contains a formula,
say the integral over `x` of some function `f(x)`. I would like to display the formula in the conventional LaTeX font style. I use the unicode `\u222b` to refer to the integral sign. So the 
text string reads `\u222b f(x)dx`. Now, when I change the Font Family property, only the text `f(x)dx` is affected, but the integral sign remains exactly the same! I find the unicode integral sign
extremely ugly, and the traditional LaTeX integral sign very beautiful, as is the case for many
other mathematical symbols as well. How can I make sure that the integral sign becomes displayed in the traditional LaTeX font style?

Please use a simple language in your answer, I am not a professional!

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: So you're trying to make LaTeX fonts appear in a WinForms application?

Answer (score 1):

If you downloaded a Computer Modern font that Windows understands, this is likely a conversion to TTF of the original representation in TeX. TeX was invented before Unicode, so these characters are probably missing from the converted font, causing Windows to fall back onto its default font.

TeX also does custom tricks, such as composing multiple glyphs into stretchable integral signs, which are not supported by the Windows font renderer.

Furthermore, using such a custom font, your application won't work properly on computers that don't have the font.

I think your best bet, sad but true, is to use LaTeX to render the equations to PNG files (with a transparent background), and use these in your UI. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/184663/export-transparent-background-equations-from-latex) on SuperUser should help you accomplish the creation of these PNGs.